# What is blocking my mysql connection?

Tags: mysql, docker, wireshark, traceroute

We run several docker images on a VM.

`sudo iptables -S` shows a lot of docker networking.

We try to connect to an external MySQL database in another net.

```
mysql --host=mysql.example.org --user=thisuser thatdatabase
```

We get error message:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysql.example.org' (115)

Network logs show that external firewall does not recognize a connect attempt.

We tried to shut down docker and try again with no avail.

```
sudo traceroute mysql.example.org
traceroute to mysql.example.org (111.222.333.444), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  localvm.example.org (172.17.0.1)  3071.799 ms !H  3071.763 ms !H  3071.754 ms !H
```

The `172.17.0.1` is -not- the ip-address from the local system.

On another vanilla system we can connect to this instance.

We tried to use a explicit route with no avail.

```
ip route add 222.333.444.0/24 dev ens192

traceroute mysql.example.org
traceroute to mysql.example.org (correct external ip-address), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
1  localvm.example.org (correct local ip-address)  3068.673 ms !H  3068.566 ms !H  3068.532 ms !H
```

Any suggestions how to narrow down errors?

Is it time to start wireshark?

VM is Debian 10, client is mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.22-MariaDB

Comment: "VM is Debian 10".  What is the host OS?

Comment: I realized that docker services added IPTABLES-rules.  Now, how do i add iptables rule to allow TCP/3306 connection to mysql.example.org?

Comment: If i want to allow connections -from- foreign systems i should use
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s aa.bb.cc.dd -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT  


But i have to allow connections -to- a foreign system.

Comment: @Gerard: Host is a well configured VMWare. VM client is Debian 10

Comment: The "external" database server has a private IP address?  Better add your routing info to the question, where you can format it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that we had to tell docker not to use 172.17.0.0/24 network.

According to [how-do-i-configure-the-default-bridge-docker0](https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-configure-the-default-bridge-docker0-network-for-docker-engine-to-a-different-subnet)

we changed

```
/etc/docker/daemon.json
{
  "bip": "172.26.0.1/16"
}

systemctl restart docker;systemctl status docker
```

Old route entry was

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         ....            0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens192
...........     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens192
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

route now shows different net:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.26.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
```

Now its not conflicting with the existing server and connection is possible.

Thanks very much to all for your help!

Comment: If you have leftover routes you can delete them with:  

route del -net 172.17.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0

Answer (score 0):

normally means that there is no MySQL server running on the system or that you are using an incorrect Unix socket file name or TCP/IP port number when trying to connect to the server. You should also check that the TCP/IP port you are using has not been blocked by a firewall or port blocking service.